# Load PowerPoint Object Library on Excel - 'Error in loading dll'

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to load the 'Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library' in VBA.

I am using a Mac and Excel 2016.

```
Sub MyPPT()
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject

Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

VBProj.References.AddFromFile Environ("systemroot") & "/system32/Microsoft PowerPoint.tlb"

Set VBProj = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time error '48':
> Error in loading DLL

Comment: The reference 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3' is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Mac user, but I'm pretty sure there is no System32 folder on a Mac. Are you sure that the path is correct?

Based on [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-object-libraries-to-your-visual-basic-project-ed28a713-5401-41b0-90ed-b368f9ae2513), the path should be something like :

```
/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app/Content/SharedSuppo...
```